# How can I set up my function arg types to be mutually conditioned upon a config structure?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
### this is my mapping data structure saying: some contexts have specific own tags
const config = {
  contexts: ["A", "B", "C"] as const,

  tags: {
    A: ["aa", "bb"] as const,
    B: ["aa1", "bb1"] as const,
    C: ["aa2", "bb2"] as const,
  },
};

# union type for contexts possible
type C = typeof config.contexts[number]; // "A" | "B" | "C"

# union type for tags specific for context U
type F<U extends C> = typeof config.tags[U][number];

const a: C = config.contexts[1]; // OK "B"

const f: F<typeof a> = "aa1"; // OK will accept only 'aa1','bb1'


# then I tried the above into a couple of function def but with NO SUCCESS

const func =  (a:C) => {
  return (g:F<typeof a>) => {}
}


func('A')(g) // ERROR g can be all of : "aa" | "bb" | "aa1" | "bb1" | "aa2" | "bb2"


const func2 =  (a:C,g:F<typeof a>) => {}


func('A',gg) // ERROR gg can be all of : "aa" | "bb" | "aa1" | "bb1" | "aa2" | "bb2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `typoeof a` does not mean capturing the actual type of the argument passed in, it just means whatever the declared type of `a` is, so in this case `C`. It works in the first case, because TS will use control flow analysis to narrow the type of `a` to `B`, since that is local information, but it will not work for functions.

To capture call site information, you need to use a type parameter:

```
const func =  <T extends C>(a:T) => {
  return (g:F<T>) => {}
}

func('A')("bb") // ok
func('A')("bb1") // err
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdTqAtgT2QQwA6egOwOagAm646os4ATgK4DG4NVApheinvgFwUD2SrOr1zhmAD3DxI6AG6tYmZnWgAzaHVC8A7rgjp8sAFBDclUCbWEAvKADeh0OeGiJsHgG0ARAEFPAGlBPACF-QIBhTwBdUHR4E0o-Qwc9Ax57R0dvD090dFDPACMCqJi44QTkxyDs3IBGfKL66NinU3BEjNAwmvQAJgaC-uayto7QAF9E8YBuJJBQGlxoYQgURVAVXipWl0lQTF5YWGgCgBtmQ3A11jDQGyvFXhVWywA6E13Yd1waJALmKiRaageY+TygAA+gRCkPCnjmYEWy10D1Ym22ZAMFEUyjUGnRO3E4FAAFVLtdQAAxAA8JNAROYuCI8DCAD47qtHs8LNB8K9MV8SZFvr9-oDZoZ5hBIIzQABJCBUaDMIjS1joAq8OQIES8GJOGiYc6aZ4qRYMZHEZjPAo0YlaaBQUAAOQA8qAAMoksJhACiHo9xnKxLNuA0NlA1IAKvSJIzmV1WQAKdBcKMASju7PSoBYjCouiT3BpUdZmas2fGhirhlDdCTAHJvA300nCsV07XzY3m632-VO0A)